# Configure mongodb property maxWaitQueueSize in Spring boot application?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I get the error `com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.` while doing a stress test on my application.

So I am thinking of configuring the `maxWaitQueueSize` property via configuration.

I am using spring boot to configure mongodb connection. I am using @EnableAutoConfiguration in my Application and I have declared  only `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:password@ip:27017` in the application.properties file.

How do I configure the `maxWaitQueueSize` property with spring boot?

How do I decide a good value for the `maxWaitQueueSize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB 3.0+, you can set `waitQueueMultiple` in your *mongouri* :

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:password@ip:27017/?waitQueueMultiple=10
```

`waitQueueMultiple` is a number that the driver multiples the `maxPoolSize` value to, to provide the maximum number of threads allowed to wait for a connection to become available from the pool.

> How do I decide a good value for the maxWaitQueueSize?

It's not directly related to MongoDB but you can read more about *Pool Sizing* in [Hikari github wiki](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Comment: what can I set for maxPoolSize? I see the default is set to 100 in MongoClientOptions.java

Comment: It has a default value but you override it based on application requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In com.mongodb.MongoClientURI, you can find the parameters which can be used in MongoClientOption.

```
        if (key.equals("maxpoolsize")) {
            builder.connectionsPerHost(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("minpoolsize")) {
            builder.minConnectionsPerHost(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("maxidletimems")) {
            builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("maxlifetimems")) {
            builder.maxConnectionLifeTime(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("waitqueuemultiple")) {
            builder.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("waitqueuetimeoutms")) {
            builder.maxWaitTime(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("connecttimeoutms")) {
            builder.connectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("sockettimeoutms")) {
            builder.socketTimeout(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else if (key.equals("autoconnectretry")) {
            builder.autoConnectRetry(_parseBoolean(value));
        } else if (key.equals("replicaset")) {
            builder.requiredReplicaSetName(value);
        } else if (key.equals("ssl")) {
            if (_parseBoolean(value)) {
                builder.socketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using spring boot starter webflux. This issue also happens. 
I tried to add MongoClientFactoryBean. It doesn't work.
The whole application is located in https://github.com/yigubigu/webfluxbenchmark. I tried to test performance benchmark of webflux and original mvc.

```
@Bean
    public MongoClientFactoryBean mongoClientFactoryBean() {
        MongoClientFactoryBean factoryBean = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setHost("localhost");
        factoryBean.setPort(27017);
        factoryBean.setSingleton(true);     
        MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .connectionsPerHost(1000)                                               
            .minConnectionsPerHost(500)
            .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(10)
            .build();
        factoryBean.setMongoClientOptions(options);
        return factoryBean;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by injecting an object of MongoOptions to your MongoTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This `maxQueueSize` limit is computed here in the Java client source code :
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.10.x/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings.java#L273

It is the product of `maxConnectionPoolSize` and `threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier` and hence can be modified through [`?maxPoolSize=`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxPoolSize) and [`?waitQueueMultiple=`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html) in the connection URI.